# fwupdateでNuttXが正しく書き込まれない

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSE SDK v2.3.0で、`examples/fwupdate`、`examples/hello`、`feature/usbmsc`を有効にしたファームウェアを2つ作成しました。
一方はソースに手を入れておらず("Hello, World!!"と表示される)、もう一方は`examples/hello`の表示を変更したものです。

```
nsh> hello
Hello, spresense!!
```

元のソースの`nuttx.spk`を`loader.espk`と結合してパッケージ化しました。

```
$ examples/fwupdate/package.sh sdk/nuttx.spk firmware/spresense/loader.espk
Pack: 1 188752 sdk/nuttx.spk
Pack: 1 129968 firmware/spresense/loader.espk
====================
Created package.bin
====================
$ cp package.bin hello.bin
```

SDにこれを書き込み、`fwupdate`でアップデートできるか確認しましたが、NuttXが正しくアップデートされていないように見えます。

```
NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-10.1.0
nsh> hello
Hello, spresense!!
nsh> fwupdate -p /mnt/sd0/test/hello.bin
FW Update Example!!
Free space 2314240 bytes
File: /mnt/sd0/test/hello.bin
Size: 318736
File: /mnt/sd0/test/hello.bin(0)
Size: 188752
Type: FW_SYS
->dl(0x2d03e550, 65536 / 188752): ret=0
->dl(0x2d03e550, 131072 / 188752): ret=0
->dl(0x2d03e550, 188752 / 188752): ret=0
File: /mnt/sd0/test/hello.bin(1)
Size: 129968
Type: FW_SYS
->dl(0x2d03e550, 65536 / 129968): ret=0
->dl(0x2d03e550, 129968 / 129968): ret=0
->update: ret=0
nsh> Package validation is OK.
                              Saving package to "loader"

NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-10.1.0
nsh> hello
Hello, spresense!!
nsh>
```

`fwupdate`の使い方に何か問題があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

使い方は合っていると思いますが、`nuttx.spk`のタイプが`1`になっているのが変です。
`Pack: 1 188752 sdk/nuttx.spk`

自分のUbuntu環境で同じコマンドを実行してみると、`nuttx.spk`のタイプは`0`になり、ファームウェアアップデートも正しく動作しています。

```
$ examples/fwupdate/package.sh sdk/nuttx.spk firmware/spresense/loader.espk
Pack: 0 148912 sdk/nuttx.spk
Pack: 1 129968 firmware/spresense/loader.espk
====================
Created package.bin
====================
```

タイプ違いが動作しない原因のような気がします。

`examples/fwupdate/package.sh` が単純なスクリプトなので中身をみてみましたが、`basename`コマンドでファイル名を取得して`nuttx`という文字列であればタイプを`0`にしているようです。環境依存の問題があるのか、何が原因なのか、はっきりとは分かりませんが、`basename`コマンドが意図した動作になっていないのかもしれません。

`spresense`ディレクトリ下で次のコマンドを実行すると何が表示されるでしょうか？期待結果は`nuttx.spk`です。

```
$ cd spresense
$ basename sdk/nuttx.spk
```

ディレクトリを`spresense/sdk`へ移動して、次のコマンドを実行するとどうでしょうか？こちらも期待結果は`nuttx.spk`です。

```
$ cd spresense/sdk
$ basename nuttx.spk
```

明確な回答にはなっていませんが、スクリプトの挙動を確認してみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: nuttx.spk 以外の名前にリネームして、package.shで結合したものを使っていたことが原因のようでした。
nuttx.spk で1からやり直したら、正しくアップデートすることが出来ました。

Comment: basenameコマンドの動作は特に問題無し、質問内容の誤記だったんですね。回答が役に立ち、解決したようで良かったです!!